# Sublime SFTP times out with known working config

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, sftp

I have a working config for my sublime SFTP on sublime 3 which I have running on a Windows device.

I've tried to set up the same exact configuration on my mac device and I get a timeout error.

The mac device can access command line sftp and filezilla just fine, but sublime sftp won't work.

Here's my config file.

```
    {
    "type": "sftp",
    "sync_down_on_open": true,
    "upload_on_save":true,
    "host": "xx.xxx.xx.xx",
    "user": "ubuntu",
    "remote_path": "/var/www",
    "connect_timeout": 120,
    "keepalive": 120,
    "ssh_key_file": "/Users/Username/.ssh/File.ppk"


}
```

All I get in response is

```
Connecting to SFTP server "xx.xxx.xx.xx" as "ubuntu" ..... failure (Connection timeout)
```

I've also tried with the aws public dns but that doesn't work either.

Any help would be really appreciated.. I've been fighting with this for hours.

Comment: The server is down?

Comment: It works fine from the command line and filezilla though :P

Comment: This same thing is happening to me. Is there a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issues since upgrading to macOS Ventura.

1. Navigate to ~/.ssh/ folder, e.g. `cd ~/.ssh/`
2. Open config with your editor
3. Add `HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa,ssh-dss` at the bottom under Host *